# Plugins for Chrome on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome, plugins

Can anyone tell me if it is or will be possible to create plugins for the Chrome iPhone app. I suspect not but it would be brilliant if you could.

Comment: That would be really awesome (plugins/addons are always great :] ) but I agree with Comradsky when he say that's not possible.

Comment: iCab has a lot of useful plugins built-in. One was able to write your own plugins in Java-Script but Apple stopped it. http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628?mt=8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**I'm sorry but I don't think there is a way to create plugins for the chrome iOS application.**

**Because**...

- The user has no way to organize these plugins in the application.
- The mobile app is very different from the full computer application,
  smaller, and doesn't need to have the capabilities of the full
  computer application.
- There isn't a way to adjust the browser settings.
- You can't download certain file types from a mobile browser.
- I think downloading these plugins to the device would be against apples policies, because there not approved by apple
- If it would ever work, google would have to offer them all in one application or have in app purchases
- Unless you jail-brake and download the full version chrome you won't be able to receive  plugins on your iOS device
- A developer outside of Google can't communicate with Googles apps

---

There are free web browser tutorials out there, instead of creating a plugin for the mobile application, why not just create your own browser. This would allow you to make some awesome "plugin-type" tools.

**Creating a mobile-browser application tutorials:**

- 2 part tutorial with web view [here](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/21/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-1/) and [here.](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/22/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-2/)
- internet browser with a search bar video @[youtube.com/.....](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vpq8r-HHwZA)

Comment: What do you mean by "jail-brake and download the full version chrome"? Do you mean that there is a full version chrome availble for jailbroken iOS devices?

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for an official source, then it seems that it is not clear whether extensions are available on chrome for iOS. What is official is that they are not for Chrome on android and are not even planned:

> **Does Chrome for Android support apps and extensions?**
>
> Chrome apps and extensions are currently not supported on Chrome for Android. We have no plans to announce at this time.

([source](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq))

I think that this strongly suggests that they are not available and not planned for iOS, too.

More in general, I think that having any kind of plug-ins, i.e., code that can be downloaded and run locally, goes against the Apple Developers Agreement.

Answer (score 3):

No, absolutely not. Apps on iOS are sandboxed. Software that isn't apps (and isn't from Apple) can't be installed on devices without jailbreaking. There is no way for any developer outside of Google to make anything that communicates with Google's apps.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to substitute some plugin functionality using a Javascript bookmarklet.

http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/30/how-to-easily-use-bookmarklets-in-google-chrome-for-ios/