# Can we have add-ons(FireFox) or extensions(Chrome) in the mobile browsers [Android or iPhone]

Tags: android, iphone, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, mobile-browser

Can we have add-ons(FireFox) or extensions(Chrome) in the mobile browsers like how we are 
using them with web browsers.

Can we do the following things:

1. Install an extension or plugin or add-on in the Mobile browser. (Mobile device can be Anything android or iPhone).
2. And can we utilize the touch and text area click events like how we are using to get them and code something ourself for our plugin use.
3. Can we use a javascript or ajax calls and accessing the browser events without using an webview.
4. I need to know that,

If user types or clicks in the text fields i have to get know that and do access the browser text field and do some useful things to do by code.

But i don't want to use separate web view application.
And i do want to stay in the browsers current view itself and do the above things.

For Android is dare needed one. Please help me out for this, i had a research a lot but i couldn't able to find the solution.

I want to know that whether we can do this or not.

I have a hope on you geeks, please give me a suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: URL to pdf adds a new menu item to chrome on android. I'm looking for how it does that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not possible to add extension on chrome for android according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604417/extension-in-google-chrome-mobile).

It is possible to have a few addons on firefox for android. Just visit the firefox addons website from you device. It probably shows only the ones that can be installed on the device.

Comment: sorry. no idea about Safari

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302047/plugins-for-chrome-on-iphone - and this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708342/ios-safari-support-plugins- It's not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can write add-on for Firefox Mobile using the [Add-on SDK](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk). Take a look to the documentation, specifically to the guide “[Developing for Firefox Mobile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/mobile.html)”.

Answer (score 3):

[Kitt](http://www.kitt.com) supports extensions on iPhone using a subset of the extension framework used by Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Chrome Beta for Android. It says you can install addons. It's, IMHO, pretty good and getting better with every revision.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta&hl=en

Comment: Where does it say you can install addons?

Comment: This is not true according to my experience. I could not add extensions or apps.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome for android still has no support for extensions. Still its pretty good browser. If you really need addons you should try Firefox for android:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox

Additionally, you can try both browser beta versions. :) Hopefully i was helpful

Comment: Why were you down repped, that was bogus, i plus repped you.

Comment: I just test Firefox for Android, and as a chrome browser fanboy I was happily surprised.  IMHO, Firefox for Android is great.  It does allow addons, and keeps the UI to a minimum conserving precious screen space.  Awesome!!!